# Removed Records: Formula from /xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml part

Tags: apache-poi

I'm generating an xlsx through apache POI SXSSFWorkbook but when I open the Excel file I have the error: "We found a problem with some content in 'prova.xlsx'. Do you want us to try to recover as much as we can? If you trust the source of this workbook click Yes". After clicking 'Yes' I have the message 'Removed Records: Formula from /xl/worksheets/sheet2.xml part'.

This is the code with formulas in my Java:

public void createSheetSX(SXSSFWorkbook workbook) throws Exception {
SXSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet(getTitle());

```
    int rownum = 0;
    
    CellStyle headerStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
    headerStyle.setBorderBottom(CellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
    headerStyle.setBorderTop(CellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
    headerStyle.setBorderRight(CellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
    headerStyle.setBorderLeft(CellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
    
    Font headerFont = workbook.createFont();
    headerFont.setFontName(getTextFont());
    headerFont.setFontHeightInPoints((short) 10);
    headerFont.setBoldweight(HSSFFont.BOLDWEIGHT_BOLD);
    headerStyle.setFont(headerFont);
    
    org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row excelRow = sheet.createRow(0);
    Cell cell0 = excelRow.createCell(0);
    cell0.setCellStyle(headerStyle);
    cell0.setCellValue("Numero polizza");
    
    org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row excelRow1 = sheet.createRow(1);
    Cell cell1 = excelRow1.createCell(0);
    cell1.setCellStyle(headerStyle);
    cell1.setCellValue("Numero veicolo");
    
   
    Cell cell2 = excelRow1.createCell(3);
    cell2.setCellStyle(headerStyle);
    org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellType formula = org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellType.FORMULA;
    cell2.setCellType(formula);
    cell2.setCellFormula("CERCA.VERT(CONCATENA(B1;\"-\";B2);atr!$A:$DU;117;FALSO)");
    
    Cell cell3 = excelRow1.createCell(4);
    cell3.setCellStyle(headerStyle);
    cell3.setCellType(formula);
    cell3.setCellFormula("CERCA.VERT(CONCATENA(B1;\"-\";B2);atr!$A:$DU;108;FALSO)");
    
    
    org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row excelRow2 = sheet.createRow(2);
    Cell cell4 = excelRow2.createCell(2);
    cell4.setCellStyle(headerStyle);
    cell4.setCellValue("NUM SIN PRINCIPALI");
    
    Cell cell5 = excelRow2.createCell(3);
    cell5.setCellStyle(headerStyle);
    cell5.setCellType(formula);
    cell5.setCellFormula("CERCA.VERT(CONCATENA(B1;\"-\";B2);atr!$A:$DU;118;FALSO)");        
    
    sheet.trackAllColumnsForAutoSizing();

}
```

How Can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Formulas in Excel files never are stored as locale formulas. They always are en_US. So

```
cell2.setCellFormula("CERCA.VERT(CONCATENA(B1;\"-\";B2);atr!$A:$DU;117;FALSO)");
```

is wrong even if you have a localized Italian Excel version. The stored formula needs to be en_US. That means function names as well as parameter delimiter as well as decimal delimiter as well as boolean literals needs to be en_US. So your correct formula set needs to be:

```
cell2.setCellFormula("VLOOKUP(CONCATENATE(B1,\"-\",B2),atr!$A:$DU,117,FALSE)");
```

Note function names en_US, so `VLOOKUP` instead of `CERCA.VERT` and `CONCATENATE` instead of `CONCATENA`, parameter delimiter en_US, so comma instead of semi colon and boolean literal en_US, so `FALSE` instead of `FALSO`.

The locale dependent changes are done in Excel GUI only and are not stored in files. So exchange of Excel files around the world is possible without the disadvantage of localized formula syntax.

Of course the same corrections have to be done for each other `.setCellFormula` calls in above code.

Comment: thank you very much for the answer! Unfortunately this correction doesn't solve the bug

Comment: Works for me. What `apache poi` version are you using?

Comment: SXSSFWorkbook.java:  version 1.6 : 50.0

Comment: @323loris: I don't know `SXSSFWorkbook.java: version 1.6 : 50.0`. From where have you got it?

Comment: the version of Apache POI is 3.16. The problem is that formulas are pulled away from Excel. I don't know why

Comment: @323loris: Cannot reproducing using the code you provided. Works for me using `apache poi 3.16` and when changed formula strings to en_US. It throws 10 warnings because of deprecated methods used. But it compiles, runs and produces a proper Excel file having the formulas in the cells.

Comment: sorry, I realized I didn't actually apply all the corrections... forgot to change the parameter delimiter en_US, so comma instead of semi colon

this solved the issue. thank you very much